# Не могу подключить кнопку к коду (PyQT5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, сигналы-слоты

у меня есть графический интерфейс калькулятора:

calc01.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_rezalt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_rezalt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rockwell Extra Bold")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_rezalt.setFont(font)
        self.label_rezalt.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_rezalt.setObjectName("label_rezalt")
        self.btn_equal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_equal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 320, 120, 80))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_equal.setFont(font)
        self.btn_equal.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 63, 5);")
        self.btn_equal.setObjectName("btn_equal")
        self.btn_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 320, 120, 80))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_0.setFont(font)
        self.btn_0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_0.setObjectName("btn_0")
        self.btn_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_7.setFont(font)
        self.btn_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_7.setObjectName("btn_7")
        self.btn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 230, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_1.setFont(font)
        self.btn_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_1.setObjectName("btn_1")
        self.btn_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 140, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_4.setFont(font)
        self.btn_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_4.setObjectName("btn_4")
        self.btn_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_5.setFont(font)
        self.btn_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_5.setObjectName("btn_5")
        self.btn_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_9.setFont(font)
        self.btn_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_9.setObjectName("btn_9")
        self.btn_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_8.setFont(font)
        self.btn_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_8.setObjectName("btn_8")
        self.btn_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 140, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_6.setFont(font)
        self.btn_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_6.setObjectName("btn_6")
        self.btn_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 230, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_2.setFont(font)
        self.btn_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_2.setObjectName("btn_2")
        self.btn_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_3.setFont(font)
        self.btn_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_3.setObjectName("btn_3")
        self.btn_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_plus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 50, 60, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_plus.setFont(font)
        self.btn_plus.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.btn_plus.setObjectName("btn_plus")
        self.btn_mines = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_mines.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 140, 60, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_mines.setFont(font)
        self.btn_mines.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.btn_mines.setObjectName("btn_mines")
        self.btn_multiply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_multiply.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 230, 60, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_multiply.setFont(font)
        self.btn_multiply.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.btn_multiply.setObjectName("btn_multiply")
        self.btn_divide = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_divide.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 320, 60, 80))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_divide.setFont(font)
        self.btn_divide.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.btn_divide.setObjectName("btn_divide")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
​
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
​
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Калькулятор"))
        self.label_rezalt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.btn_equal.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))
        self.btn_0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.btn_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.btn_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.btn_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.btn_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.btn_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.btn_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.btn_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.btn_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.btn_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.btn_plus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.btn_mines.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.btn_multiply.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.btn_divide.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
```

и код где этот файл импортируется:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from calc01 import Ui_MainWindow
​
class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
​
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
​
        self.ui.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.ui.label_rezalt.display('1'))
​
​
​
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

без 12 строки
`self.ui.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.ui.label_rezalt.display('1'))` все работает а как только я пытаясь считать значение с кнопки, добавляю эту 12 строку, оно выдает ошибку:

```
File "G:\Python\test\test.py", line 12
    self.ui.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.ui.label_rezalt.display('1'))
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Код вставьте в  сам вопрос. Для оформления кода нужно на строке перед кодом и после кода поставить три косых апострофа ```

Comment: там просто строчек 100 или даже больше в самом интерфейсе

Comment: Проверьте строку и те что выше, чтобы у них в отступах использовались или только пробелы, или только табы. Кст, а что за метод `.display('1')`? Вангую, что вам там нужен будет метод `setText`. И, думаю, там не хватает лямбды, типа: `self.ui.btn_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.label_rezalt.setText('1'))`

Comment: Да, вроде этот вопрос решился, только теперь выдает: "AttributeError: 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'display' ", тоже не понимает что такое '''.display''', попробую сам решить проблему, спасибо

Comment: @RONG_VANG у вас код порядка 8000 тысяч символов, а максимум - 50000, так что без проблем должно вставиться. А вообще да, нужно отступы табами заменить на отступы пробелами.

Comment: Спасибо всем, вроде даже почти работает!

Comment: @RONG_VANG, пожалуйста :) Пишите @<ник>, чтобы уведомления приходили о комментарии ;)

Comment: @insolor , я просто подумал что так будет культурнее тк я не буду загромождать вопрос, а кто действительно хочет помочь откроет код

Comment: @gil9red , конечно, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_rezalt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_rezalt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rockwell Extra Bold")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_rezalt.setFont(font)
        self.label_rezalt.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_rezalt.setObjectName("label_rezalt")
        self.btn_equal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_equal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 320, 120, 80))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_equal.setFont(font)
        self.btn_equal.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 63, 5);")
        self.btn_equal.setObjectName("btn_equal")
        self.btn_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 320, 120, 80))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_0.setFont(font)
        self.btn_0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_0.setObjectName("btn_0")
        self.btn_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_7.setFont(font)
        self.btn_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_7.setObjectName("btn_7")
        self.btn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 230, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_1.setFont(font)
        self.btn_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_1.setObjectName("btn_1")
        self.btn_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 140, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_4.setFont(font)
        self.btn_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_4.setObjectName("btn_4")
        self.btn_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_5.setFont(font)
        self.btn_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_5.setObjectName("btn_5")
        self.btn_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_9.setFont(font)
        self.btn_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_9.setObjectName("btn_9")
        self.btn_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_8.setFont(font)
        self.btn_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_8.setObjectName("btn_8")
        self.btn_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 140, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_6.setFont(font)
        self.btn_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_6.setObjectName("btn_6")
        self.btn_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 230, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_2.setFont(font)
        self.btn_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_2.setObjectName("btn_2")
        self.btn_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 230, 80, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_3.setFont(font)
        self.btn_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54, 166, 200);")
        self.btn_3.setObjectName("btn_3")
        self.btn_plus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_plus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 50, 60, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_plus.setFont(font)
        self.btn_plus.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.btn_plus.setObjectName("btn_plus")
        self.btn_mines = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_mines.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 140, 60, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_mines.setFont(font)
        self.btn_mines.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.btn_mines.setObjectName("btn_mines")
        self.btn_multiply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_multiply.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 230, 60, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_multiply.setFont(font)
        self.btn_multiply.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.btn_multiply.setObjectName("btn_multiply")
        self.btn_divide = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_divide.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 320, 60, 80))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(17)
        self.btn_divide.setFont(font)
        self.btn_divide.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        self.btn_divide.setObjectName("btn_divide")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Калькулятор"))
        self.label_rezalt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.btn_equal.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))
        self.btn_0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.btn_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.btn_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.btn_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.btn_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.btn_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.btn_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.btn_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.btn_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.btn_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.btn_plus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.btn_mines.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.btn_multiply.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.btn_divide.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        
        
class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)

#        self.btn_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.label_rezalt.display('1'))
        self.btn_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.label_rezalt.setText('1'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @RONG_VANG что не так?

Comment: Теперь все так, спасибо огромное!!!!

Comment: Если это калькулятор, то наверняка нужно будет накапливать изменения, т.е. типа `self.label_rezalt.setText(self.label_rezalt.text() + '1')`, а лучше в отдельный метод вынести :)